# Evaluating $\int\frac{1-x+x\ln x}{\ln^2 x}dx$.

Tags: integration

I am looking to integrate the function below. I have the final result but I am not getting the solution from my approach. Any assistance would be helpful.

\begin{equation}
 \int \frac{1-x+x \ln x}{\ln^2 x} dx = -\text{Ei}(2 \ln x)+\frac{x(x-1)}{\ln x} + \text{li}(x)
\end{equation}

where $\text{Ei}(x)$ and $\text{li}(x)$ are the exponential integral and logarithmic integral, respectively.

My attempt is as follows:

Substituting $u = \ln x$, we obtain $du = \frac{1}{x}dx$, or $x du = dx$.

\begin{equation}
 \int \frac{1-e^u+ue^u}{u^2e^u}du = \int\frac{e^{-u}-1+u}{u^2}du 
\end{equation}

Solving this provides

\begin{equation}
-\frac{e^{-u}}{u}-\text{Ei}(-u)+\frac{1}{u}-\ln u
\end{equation}

Resubstituting $x$ for $u$-terms, provides

\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{x\ln x}- \text{Ei}(-\ln x) + \frac{1}{\ln x} - \ln \ln x
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't substituted correctly: $u=\ln x\Rightarrow x=e^u\Rightarrow dx=e^u\,du$ and we obtain
$$I=\int\frac{1-e^u+ue^u}{u^2}\cdot e^u\,du=\int \frac{e^u-e^{2u}+ue^{2u}}{u^2}\,du$$
Note the $e^u$ is in the numerator and not the denominator, as you've done. Then we can integrate by parts:
$$I=\left(e^u-e^{2u}+ue^{2u}\right)\left(-\frac 1u\right)+\int\frac{e^u-e^{2u}+2ue^{2u}}{u}\,du $$ And
$$\int\frac{e^u}{u}\,du=\operatorname{Ei}(u)+C \\
\int\frac{e^{2u}}{u}\,du=\operatorname{Ei}(2u)+C \\
\int\frac{2ue^{2u}}{u}\,du=\int 2e^{2u}\,du=e^{2u}+C $$
The remaining part is to back-substitute $u=\ln x$. Also, note that $\operatorname{Ei}(\ln x)=\operatorname{li}(x)$.

Comment: Stupid oversight on my part. Thank you!